# LateInitializationError: Field '_cityEntered@20328536' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I've been trying to initial string _cityEntered to use into all my widgets. As you can see i've intialized using late keyword. And then i've initialized the string into if statement. But when i'm running the code i'm getting this error everytime. It's saying i've not initialized the string. LateInitializationError: Field '_cityEntered@20328536' has not been initialized.

Now the problem is chenged to this again: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

```
      import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:climate_app/ui/climatic.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:climate_app/util/utils.dart' as util;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Climatic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClimaticState createState() => _ClimaticState();
}

class _ClimaticState extends State<Climatic> {
  String? _cityEntered;
  Future _goToNextScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    Map results = await Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return CityWeather();
    }));
    if (results != null && results.containsKey("enter")) {
      _cityEntered = results["enter"];
      // print(results['enter'].toString());
    }
  }

  void showData() async {
    Map _whetherData = await getWheather(util.appID, util.defaultCity);
    print(_whetherData.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Climatic"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _goToNextScreen(context);
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu))
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Image.asset(
              "images/umbrella.png",
              width: 490.0,
              height: 1200.0,
              fit: BoxFit
                  .fill, 
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.9, 20.0, 0.0),
            child: Text(
              "${_cityEntered == null ? util.defaultCity : _cityEntered}",
              style: cityStyle(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Image.asset("images/light_rain.png"),
          ),
          // container which will contain our weather data
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 400.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: updateTempWidget(_cityEntered ?? 'Dhaka'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  Future<Map> getWheather(String appID, String city) async {
    String apiURL =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=$city&appid=${util.appID}&units=metric";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiURL));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Widget updateTempWidget(String city) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getWheather(util.appID, city == null ? util.defaultCity : city),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {
          
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            Map content = snapshot.data ?? {};
            
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      content["main"][
                              "temp"] 
                          .toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 49.9,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
}


class CityWeather extends StatelessWidget {
  CityWeather({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  var _cityController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("City Weather"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: Stack(children: [
        Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            "images/white_snow.png",
            width: 499.9,
            height: 1200.0,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter your City"),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                controller: _cityController,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, {'enter': _cityController.text});
                },
                child: Text('Get Weather'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}



TextStyle cityStyle() {
  // here for the style into our container we created a separate method and onto that we've designed our text as we wanted
  return TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.9, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
}

TextStyle tempStyle() {
  return TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
      fontSize: 49.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);
}
```

Comment: Can you include full widget

Comment: Please check. Chaning the code according to you is throuwing the previous error now.

Answer (score 0):

You are intilizing only if `results != null && results.containsKey("enter")` condition is meet, but other cases it will not assinged.

make it nullable

```dart
 String? _cityEntered;
```

While using `_cityEntered` check if it is null, like

```
if(_cityEntered!=null) doYourStuff
```

Or provide default value on null cases like

```dart
_cityEntered?? "default value"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are promising the compiler that you will initialize the `_cityEntered` but it happens only if `results != null && results.containsKey("enter")` condition is met.

So the compiler is throwing the error. To overcome this just

Change

```
late _cityEntered name;
```

to

```
String? _cityEntered;
```

Comment: please check the full widget, not working. Throwing another error